# "Too Many Connections" error even though dataSource.getActive() returns 0?

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat

Im very sure i am closing the con,rs,stmt in the finally block. But seems to get the "too many connections" error at the 4th try of trying to execute an update.

```
public boolean setUserSettings(UserSettings userSettings)
{
    ResultSet rs = null;
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    String _query;

    try
    {
        System.out.println("total current connections: " + dataSource.getActive());
        con = dataSource.getConnection();
        _query = Util.readIn("/sql/select/selectUserSettingsCount.sql", MySqlPersistence.class);
        stmt = con.prepareStatement(_query);
        stmt.setString(1, userSettings.user);

        rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        boolean found = rs.next() && rs.getInt(1) == 1;

        if (!found)
        {
            _query = Util.readIn("/sql/insert/setUserSettings.sql", MySqlPersistence.class);
            stmt = con.prepareStatement(_query);
            stmt.setString(1, userSettings.user);
            stmt.setBoolean(2, userSettings.isActive);
            stmt.setString(3, userSettings.phone);
            stmt.setString(4, userSettings.phone2);
            stmt.setString(5, userSettings.phone3);
            stmt.setString(6, userSettings.contact_strategy);
        }
        else
        {               
            _query = Util.readIn("/sql/update/updateUserSettings.sql", MySqlPersistence.class);
            stmt = con.prepareStatement(_query);
            stmt.setString(1, userSettings.phone);
            stmt.setString(2, userSettings.phone2);
            stmt.setString(3, userSettings.phone3);
            stmt.setString(4, userSettings.user);
        }

        int success = stmt.executeUpdate();
        if (found && success == 1)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {                
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {            
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    finally
    {
        try { if (rs != null) System.out.println("closing rs"); rs.close(); } catch (SQLException e) { }
        try { if (stmt != null) System.out.println("closing stmt"); stmt.close(); } catch (SQLException e) { }
        try { if (con != null) System.out.println("closing con"); con.close(); } catch (SQLException e) { }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you prepare the statement twice?

Comment: im sure it was just bad copy/paste, there's only one stmt there. sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create 2 Statements per method call, but only close 1.  Before you enter the first big `if` block, you should close the existing statement.

UPDATE:

upon further reflection, i noticed another error in your code.  this pattern is broken:

```
if (con != null) System.out.println("closing con"); con.close();
```

it is, in fact, a fantastic example for why you should always use braces with if blocks.  reformatted, this code is:

```
if (con != null) 
    System.out.println("closing con"); 
con.close();
```

what you really want, however, is:

```
if (con != null) {
    System.out.println("closing con"); 
    con.close();
}
```

Comment: strangely, it worked in my tests(after closing the stmt), but when i deploy the project, it breaks at the 4th try.

Comment: @yaojiang - you most likely don't have the same resource constraints in test that you do in the environment to which you deployed.

Comment: no, everything is the same. i test/deploy to dev env so all the credentials etc are the same.

Comment: i basically did a Runnable test with multiple threads, about 60 insertions total, all of them ran fine.

Comment: @yaojiang - are you trying to say that you don't understand what the problem is?  is my answer not clear enough?

Comment: good catch on the brackets. in the end it was something from the db side, not my code that caused the problem.